# httpd.exe error while starting hp loadrunner webtour

Tags: loadrunner

I am getting `httpd.exe error` while starting `Hp Loadrunner Webtour`.

I also have tried re configuring through config file to listen to a different port but to no avail. Every time I click on start server bat file I am getting this screen.

[This is the screen I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a951g.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly an error. It is just a warning. You could still go ahead and launch the application without any qualms. In order to launch the application in the browser, go to `Start --> All Programs --> HP Software --> HP Web Tours Application`.

However, if you still want to do away with the warning, please follow the reference link. https://askubuntu.com/questions/256013/could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-name

Hope that helps!